# Unused argument error when creating an S4 object in R

Tags: r, r-s4

Am new to R programming so this might be a relatively simple error. Currently facing an issue whereby I get an *unused argument error* whenever I try to set arguments for the S4 object that I've created. What might be the solution for my issue here? Thank you!

Code:

```
fooS4 <- setClass("fooS4", slots = c(x= "numeric", y= "numeric"))  # Runs normally
obj <- fooS4(x=3,y=3)  #Error arise from this code
```

Output:

```
> Error in new("fooS4", ...) : unused arguments ("fooS4", y = 3)
```

Comment: Unable to reproduce.  Your code runs without error for me and produces the expected result.

Comment: Same as Limey --- are you running this in a fresh R session? In particular, have you overwritten the definition of the function `new`?

Comment: Oh my, yes. I had accidentally overwritten the new function. Thank you both very much!!